# Mysql search tables find datetime fields and change timezone

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have tables in my legacy database that stored dates in CST format. Now I want to store them in UTC.

I want to create a script/query, in mysql, that would search my database for tables with `datetime` fields and then convert the values there to UTC.

A script that would do this without having to write table names would be fun.

> I have the query to convert time zone with `CONVERT_TZ`, that is not
>   a problem with me. But I want a script that searches through the
>   database for tables and fields that has datetime as data type and then
>   run the script on those fields.

Any idea how I can do that? Any reference would be nice, doesn't have to be code.

Comment: @HaotianLiu I got the conversion part done. I am doing it one by one, I was wondering if I could do a search and replace throughout the table on all the fields that had datetime field type.

Comment: You can try querying the information_schema db of mysql to determine tables with datetime columns

Comment: use information_schema;
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM COLUMNS WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'datetime';

Comment: @SworupShakya Updated my solution, and it works in my local environment. Don't know whether it is the best practice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch the columns first, traverse the array to decide if it matches the `Type` you want.

Then make the update is just fine.

```
<?php
$db = new Mysqli("host", "user", "pass", "db");

$column_query = $db->query("SHOW COLUMNS IN table");
if ($column_query->num_rows != 0){
    while ($column = $column_query->fetch_object()){
        if ($column->Type != 'datetime')
            continue;
        $db->query("UPDATE table SET {$column->Field}=CONVERT_TZ({$column->Field}, 'timezoneFrom', 'timezoneTo' )");
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated solution, does this help? @Sworup Shakya